# Create custom coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, datum

I have the following info from a data provider and need to create a custom coordinate system using these parameters. The end goals is to map a file in this coordinate system against other data sources that are in a known coordinate system. Anyone have ideas?

*

> use the Geocentric Datum for Australia,1994 (GDA94)  as their mapping
>   datum, with the  Lambert Conformal Conic (LCC) projection used in the
>   CPR2 system System 1980 (GRS80) for which the  major semi-axis a = 6 378 137
>   metres exactly and an  inverse flattening (l/f) of 298.257 222 101.
>
> The parameters for the LCC projection are: Standard parallels : 15
>   degrees South , 39 degrees South. True origin of X,Y Cartesian
>   coordinates : Intersection of Lat 27 degrees South and Long 134
>   degrees East False Origin for E,N Cartesian coordinates : 5,000,000
>   metres West and 5,000,000 metres South of the true origin.
>
> All coordinates given in LCC are E,N ie false origin and in centimetres in
>   CPR.    When viewing the data in GDD, the coordinates will display in
>   metres.LCC uses the reference ellipsoid  Geodetic ReferenceAll

*

I've tried to create a .prj file for use in ESRI software (AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.5\ArcMap\Coordinate Systems\zzz.prj). Here is the result of that but defining a data doesn't correctly line up after defining a projection using this prj file:

INCORRECT:

> PROJCS["zzz",GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994",DATUM["D_GDA_1994",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",5000000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",5000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",134.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",-15.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",39.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

CORRECT ANSWER (Standard_Parallel_2 needed to be : -39.0)

> PROJCS["GDA 1994 LCC CPR2
>   T",GEOGCS["GCS_GRS_1980",DATUM["D_GRS_1980",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",5000000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",5000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",134.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",-15.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",-39.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",-27.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: Standard Parallel 2 needs to be negative. Latitude of Origin is -27. With that, I think the false easting/northing values are correct to be positive values but it should easy to determine which after fixing those two angular parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you misinterpreted False Northing/False Easting, where both should be in the negatives. The screen shot below shows a solution via GDAL. Drop the *-p* to generate a PRJ for ArcMap's use. (The *-p* is for human consumption.)

[image]

Comment: false easting and northing were correct in the end at 500000